# Freemarker: Reformat String

Tags: string, freemarker

I have a Freemarker variable that can contain strings like:

```
myFirstStringExample
mySecondStringExample
myABCStringExample
myExample
```

I need to remove the final 'Example' which will be any possible string.
I want to end up with the following strings:

```
My First String
My Second String
My ABC String
My
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more an algorithms question than a FreeMarker question, but here you go:

```
<#function camelCaseToCapWordsButLast(s)>
  <#return s
      <#-- "fooBar" to "foo bar": -->
      ?replace('([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2', 'r')
      <#-- "FOOBar" to "FOO Bar": -->
      ?replace('([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])', '$1 $2', 'r')
      <#-- and the easy part: -->
      ?cap_first?keep_before_last(' ')
  >
</#function>

${camelCaseToCapWordsButLast('myFirstStringExample')}
${camelCaseToCapWordsButLast('mySecondStringExample')}
${camelCaseToCapWordsButLast('myABCStringExample')}
${camelCaseToCapWordsButLast('myExample')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with something like this:

```
<#assign test="myFirstStringExample" />
<#assign first=test?matches("([a-z]+).*")?groups[1]?cap_first />
<#assign words=test?matches("([A-Z][a-z]*)") />
${first} <#list words as word><#if word?has_next>${word} </#if></#list>
```

It doesn't work only for `myABCStringExample`